# using Ninject with UnitOfWork and Repository (ADO not EF)

Tags: c#, ado.net, ninject, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using a unit of work and repository pattern for ado - [cribbed from jgauffin](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/01/09/unit-of-work-sample-implementation-for-ado-net/)

I am also trying to use DI (ninject) but am struggling to be clear as to how to deal with both the safe disposal of the repositories and UoW and how they should be instantiated (scopes etc)

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable{
void SaveChanges();
SqlCommand CreateCommand();
}

public IItemRepository{
List<Item> GetForParent(int parentID);
Item GetById(int id);
bool Update(Item item);
}
```

without DI i would use this thus, with no special constructor for the controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateItem(Item item){
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        var repo = new ItemRepository(uow);
        if (repo.GetByID(item.ID) == null) return NotFound();
        if (!repo.Update(item)) return BadRequest("Unable to update Item");
        uow.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }   
}
```

**am i right in assuming that I should instead do the following**, because to make a save I need to uow and even though it is already injected into the repository constructor `public ItemRepository(IUnitOfWork uow){_unitOfWork = uow;}`

the controller needs it too..

```
IItemRepository _repo;
IUnitOfWork _uow;

public ItemController(IItemRepository repo, IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    _repo = repo;
    _uow = uow;
}

public IHttpActionResult UpdateItem(Item item){
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

    if (_repo.GetByID(item.ID) == null) return NotFound();
    if (_repo.Update(item)){
        _uow.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest("Unable to update item");
}
```

and make sure that ninject creates the unitofwork with the correct scope

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IItemRepository>().To<ItemRepository>();
```

I do understand that this may not be the correct way to set up the UoW and Repositories together, and would welcome any suggestions

Comment: Why don't you using `using` statement to dispose your UoW? In my understanding you should wrap your repository with UoW, do all necessary work, and then commit changes and dispose it.

Comment: i was under the impression that as Ninject created the instance, it was up to it to dispose of it. the UoW concrete implementation has a dispose method which disposes of the connection and clears any transaction that it is using

Comment: Ok I see that Ninject disposes all objects not in transient scope. Where are you creating your UoW? From my perspective it seems that you are correctly disposing it.

Answer (score 0):

In other implementations I've seen, the UoW has methods to access the individual repositories, and so you would get a repository using `_uow.ItemRepository` (or `_uow.Repository<MyItem>` or somesuch). This is essentially what EF does: the UoW is the `DbContext`, and it exposes `DbSet`s which are analogous to the repositories.

So, for DI, you'd inject your UoW but not the repositories. (Or you'd inject a UoW *factory*, from which you would create the UoW directly, as in `using (var uow = _uowFactory.Create())...`

Comment: Regarding the final paragraph, I prefer UoW factory to Ninject for creating the UoW. That way the scope is much clearer in the code and much less prone to error. Ninject is then used to create the UoW factory rather than the UoW.